# parse XML using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have the following XML node:

```
<reportDataRow>
    <columnData colNum="1">
        <data>FirstName</data>
    </columnData>
    <columnData colNum="2">
        <data>LastName</data>
    </columnData>
</reportDataRow>
```

I want to retrieve the value from the `data` node based on the value of the `colNum` attribute in the `columnData` node.

How would I accomplish that using LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

again assuming reportDataRow is an XElement and value is a variable that you want to match the colNum attribute with;

```
foreach (var selected in reportDataRow.Elements("columnData").Where(a =>a.Attribute("colNum").Value == value))
        {
            yield return selected.Element("data").Value;
        }
```

usage will change based on how you want it

Comment: i like this better than xpath personally

Comment: @Michael, according to this, there is a noticeable performance hit in using XPathSelectElements() vs. Labroo's solution using Elements():

http://blog.dreamlabsolutions.com/post/2008/12/04/LINQ-to-XML-and-LINQ-to-XML-with-XPath-performance-review.aspx

Comment: @Kevin D -  That is a huge difference in performance.  I will be implementing this solution.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use XPathSelectElement.  Assuming that reportDataRow is an XElement representing the root element, and value is a variable that you want to match the colNum attribute with:

```
reportDataRow.XPathSelectElement(".//data[parent::columnData/@colNum = '" + value + "']");
```

Comment: The `reportDataRow` node is not the original root element, but is comes from `IEnumerable<XElement>` collection.  That particular method does not appear in the intellsense.

Comment: Sorry, you need to make sure to reference the System.Xml.XPath namespace for the method to appear.